# How to print byte tags for Pixelsense ( Samsung SUR40)?

Tags: pixelsense

I found several websites which link to the microsoft download center (e.g. [print byte tag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pixelsense/2010/11/22/how-do-i-print-tags/)) but none of those links are working. Do you know how to print new byte tags or is there a working online source? The look like [this](https://www.hometoys.com/images/upload/images/Data%20Tags.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a github repo where someone uploaded a pdf with the tags ([link](https://github.com/informatik-mannheim/pixelsense-konfigurator/blob/master/tags.pdf))